# How to trigger update in React using Effect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

A react component contains an input field and the default value of the field is passed to this component as props. User can update this value but the parent component is able to reset it. I use effect hook to do so. However, the effect does not trigger because variable "initialValue" has not changed. How to fix this?

Child component:

```
export const InputFieldComponent = ({ initialValue }: Props) => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(initialValue ?? "");

    useEffect(() => {
        setInputValue(initialValue ?? "");
    }, [initialValue]);

....
}
```

Parent component:

```
   const Parent = () => {
        const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("default value");
    
        return (
            <div>
                 <InputFieldComponent
                    initialValue={inputValue}
                />
                <button onClick={() => setInputValue("default value")}>reset</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

In real life I only need to empty input field which I can do by alternately changing initialValue prop to null or empty string, but it is a hack which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `state` have not been changed, so `childComponent` doesn't render. You can achieve your aim with another state:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

type Props = {
  initialValue: string;
  reset: boolean;
};

export const InputFieldComponent = ({ initialValue, reset }: Props) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInputValue(initialValue);
  }, [reset]);

  return (
    <input
      value={inputValue}
      defaultValue={initialValue}
      onChange={(e) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
      }}
    />
  );
};

const Parent = () => {
  const [reset, setReset] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div>
      <InputFieldComponent reset={reset} initialValue={"default value"} />
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          setReset(!reset);
        }}
      >
        reset
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return <Parent />;
}
```

[image: Edit cold-microservice-pwgox]

**Update:**

Another and better solution is using from `ref`, `createRef` and `forwardRef` functionality. You can assign `ref` to your child component and change it via parent component:

```
import { useState, createRef, forwardRef } from "react";

type Props = {
  initialValue: string;
};

export const InputFieldComponent = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, Props>(
  ({ initialValue }: Props, ref) => {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(initialValue);

    return (
      <input
        ref={ref}
        value={inputValue}
        defaultValue={initialValue}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setInputValue(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
    );
  }
);

const Parent = () => {
  const ref = createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
  const onClick = () => {
    if (ref.current) ref.current.value = "default Value";
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <InputFieldComponent ref={ref} initialValue="default Value" />
      <button onClick={onClick}>reset</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return <Parent />;
}
```

[image: Edit keen-wood-ht4rb]

Comment: This will work, but I try to avoid passing an additional boolean toggle

Comment: @lekso I've updated my answer. Please check it again.